A problem about a set containing all sums of two elements from another set

Let $A$ = {$1$, $a$$1$, $a$$2$,..., $a$$18$, $77$} be a set of integers with $1$< $a$$1$< $a$$2$<...<$a$$18$< $77$. Let the set $A+A$ = {$x+y$: $x,y\in A$} contain exactly 39 elements. Then, the value of $a$$1$+ $a$$2$+...+$a$$18$ is equal to :

My approach:
|  |  | | | |
| -------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| $1$ + $1$ | $1$ + $a$$1$| .... | $1$ + $a$$18$ | $1$ + $77$
| $a$$1$ + $1$ | $a$$1$ + $a$$1$ | ...| ... | $a$$1$ + $77$
| : | | | | :
| : | | | | $a$$18$ + $77$
| | | | | $77$ + $77$
Consider the first row. Every element in it is distinct. If they were not,
$a$$i$ + $1$ = $a$$j$ + $1$
$\Rightarrow$ $a$$i$ = $a$$j$,
which is not possible. Similarly, each element in the last column is also distinct. This table has 20 rows and 20 columns, so the elements present in first row and last column are our 39 distinct elements $\in A + A$. Note that the rest of the elements present in the table are duplicates. Now, apparently the only possible way this can happen is if.
$1$+$1$, $a$$1$ + $1$, ,..., $a$$18$ + $1$, $1$ + $77$, $a$$1$ + $77$,..., $a$$18$ + $77$, $77$ + $77$ (ie, distinct elements) are in Arithmetic Progression. How do I prove this claim?

Hint: Can you find another 39 elements with distinct sums? This way, you can compare them. If we can show that $a_1 + a_1 = 1 + a_2$, then $1, a_1, a_2$ are in an AP.

Well, yes, there is the principle diagonal with distinct sums of form  $a$$i$ + $a$$i$. But what do you mean by "compare them"? With what? @CalvinLin

$a_i + a_i$ must be $18$ distinct terms.  And $a_i + a_i < a_i + a_{i+1} < a_{i+1} + a_{i+1}$ so $a_i + a_{i+i}$ must be $17$ others.  This does not include $1+1; 77+77; a_1 + 1$ or $77 + a_i$.  So you have the sums of $\sum (a_i+a_i) + \sum (a_i + a_{i+1})+2+154+2a_1 +78 = 20 + \sum a_i + 20\times 77 \sum a_i - a_1$

You are correct.  $1+1 < 1+a_1 < .... < 1+a_{18} < 1+77 < a_1 +77 < a_2 + 77 < .... <a_{18} +77 < 77$ must be the $39$ distinct sums.
But $a_i + a_i$ must be $18$ distinct duplicates.  And $a_{i} +a_{i+1}$ are $17$ distinct (because if $i < j$ then $a_i + a_{i+1} < a_j + a_{j+1}$) duplicates.  And as for all $k \le i$ and all $i+1 <  m$ we have $a_k + a_k < a_i + a_{i+1}< a_m + a_m$ these are distinct from all $a_i + a_i$.
So $\{a_i + a_i\}\cup \{a_i + a_{i+1}\}$ are $35$ of the $39$ distinct sums.
This collection does not include:  $1+1, 1+a_1, a_{18}+77$ nor $77+77$.  So it must include all the other terms.
So $\sum_{i=1}^{18} (a_i + a_i) +\sum_{i=1}^{17}(a_i + a_{i+1})$ must equal $\sum_{i=2}^{18}(1+a_i)+(1+77) + \sum_{i=1}^{17} (77 + a_i)$.
Now it's just calculations.
$\sum_{i=1}^{18} (a_i + a_i) +\sum_{i=1}^{17}(a_i + a_{i+1})=\sum_{i=2}^{18}(1+a_i)+78 + \sum_{i=1}^{17} (77 + a_i)$
$2\sum_{i=1}^{18}a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{17}a_i + \sum_{i=2}^{18}a_i = 17+ \sum_{i=2}^{18}a_i +78+ 17\times 77 +\sum_{i=1}^{17} a_i$
$2\sum_{i=1}^{18}a_i = 17 +78+ 17\times 77 = 17\times 78+78=18\times 78$
$\sum_{i=1}^{18}a_i = 18\times 39$
====
Hmmm.... I suppose I haven't actually shown that it's possible to have such terms with exactly $39$ sums.  But if it is, the terms must add to $18\times 39$.
====
Actually, $a_i = 4i + 1$ ought to do it.   $a_i + a_j = 4(i + j) + 2$.  If $i+j \le 18$ then $4(i+j) + 2 = 4(i+j)+1 + 1 = a_{i+j}+1$.  If $i+j=19$ then $4(i+j) + 2 = 4\times 19 + 2=77 + 1$. And if $i+j > 19$ then $4(i+j) + 2 = 4(i+j-19) + 76+ 2 =4(i+j-19) + 1 + 77 = a_{i+j-19} + 77$.  If we allow the notation $a_0 = 1; a_{19}=77$ those are $39$ distinct sums.
And, of course, $\sum_{i=1}^{18} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{18}(4i + 1)= 18+4\frac {18\times 19}2=18+2(18\times 19)=18\times 39$.
=====
I haven't proven that $a_i = 4i + 1$ is the only such sequence-- only that $\sum a_i = 18\times 39$.
But we know that the distinct thirty-nine sums are:
$s_1 = 1+1$
$s_2= 1+a_1$
$s_3= 1+a_2 = a_1 + a_1$ so $a_2=2a_1 -1$
$s_4 = 1+a_3 = a_1 + a_2$ so $a_3 = 3a_1 - 2$
$s_5 = 1+a_4 = a_2 + a_2$ so $a4 = 4a_1 -3$
.....
$s_{19} = 1+a_{18}=a_9 + a_9$
$s_{20} = 1+ 77 = a_9 + a_{10}$
$s_{21} = 77+ a_1 = a_{10}+a_{10}$
.....
$s_{35}= 77 + a_{15}=a_{17}+a_{17}$
$s_{36}= 77 + a_{16}=a_{17} + a_{18}$
$s_{37}= 77 + a_{17}=a_{18} + a_{18}$
$s_{38} = 77 + a_{18}$
$s_{39} = 77 + 77$
It's too early and I haven't had my coffee, for me do make the claim that we can conclude by induction that $s_{20} = 1+77 = a_9 + a_{10} = (9a_1 -8) + (10a_1 - 9)= 19a_1-17$ so $95 =19a_1$ so $a_1 =5$ and by induction $a_i = 4i + 1$ is the only such sequence....
.... but I'd bet anything the induction would be sound for anyone willing to sit down with paper and do it.
=====
Although....
you claimed "Now, apparently the only possible way this can happen is if.
1
+1, a1 + 1, ,..., a18 + 1, 1 + 77, a1 + 77,..., a18 + 77, 77 + 77 (ie, distinct elements) are in Arithmetic Progression."
I'll admit I didn't read into you post too carefully to see why you made this claim.
But if it is true.  Then if $\sum a_i = 18\times 19$ (so the average $a_i$ is $39$) and if $a_i$ is an arithmetic progression, I didn't need to do that induction above.  If $a_i$ is AP and $a_0=1$ and and $a_{19} = 77$ then $a_i = 4i + 1$ is the only possibility.

Great explanation @fleablood ! Just a question, how did you realise that $a$$i$ = $4i$ + $1$ ? Was that observation?

@CalvinLin Where did I ever claim that that $a_i=4i+1$ is the only solution?  I only claimed it was a solution.  The question was what the sum had to be and that is all I claimed to have done.

@PratyushBiswas  You came up with that all the sums were off the form $a_i + 1$ or $a_j + 77$.  So $a_i + a_i$ had to equal $a_j + 1$ for some and $a_i + a_{i+1} = a_n + 1$ so I figured that $a_j$ were all odd and the average $18$ so... It was a guess.  Note, as Calvin Lin pointed out and as I never claimed, I haven'g shown that there it is the only solution.

Argh... I meant the average was $39$; not $18$.  (My first idea was $a_i = 2i + 1$ and averaging $18$ but that obviously failed quickly)

Let $a_0 = 1, a_{19} = 77$ for simplicity.
OP has observed that we have a chain of 39 distinct sums
$$ a_0 + a_0 < a_0 + a_1 < a_0 + a_2 < a_0 + a_3 <  \ldots a_0 + a_{19} < a_1 + a_{19} < \ldots < a_{19} + a_{19} .$$
OP has mentioned in the comments that there's also another chain of 39 distinct sums  $$a_0 + a_0 < a_0 + a_1 < a_1 + a_1 < a_1 + a_2 < a_2 + a_2 < \ldots < a_{18} + a_{18} < a_{18}+a_{19} < a_{19} + a_{19}. $$
Since both of these sequences contain all the distinct elements of $A+A$, they are the same sequence,  so we can equate them termwise to conclude that

$a_0 + a_0 = a_0 + a_0$ -> No new information
$a_0 + a_1 = a_0 + a_1 $ -> No new information
$a_0 + a_2 = a_1 + a_1 $ -> Hence $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are in an AP
$a_0 + a_3 = a_1 + a_2 $ -> Hence $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ are in an AP (with previous)
$a_0 + a_4 = a_2 + a_2 $ -> Hence $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are in an AP (with previous)
$a_0 + a_5 = a_2 + a_3 $ -> Hence $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ are in an AP (with previous)
$\vdots$
$a_1 + a_{19} = a_{10} + a_{10}$ -> Hence $a_i$ are in an AP (with previous)

Notes

The condition that $a_i$ are integers is not required.
Thus $a_i = 1 + 4i$.


"OP has mentioned in the comments that there's also another chain of 39 distinct sums "  The OP mentioned that??  Since you nitpicked my post, I'll nitpick yours and point out that you haven't answer the question what $\sum a_i$ is.  "At most" you have only shown that $a_i$ is an arithmetic progression and $a_i = 1+4i$ is the only one possible.  ;-)

@fleablood   OP said " there is the principle diagonal with distinct sums ", which I creatively interpreted. $\quad$    Ah, but OP was actually asking to prove the claim that the sequence is an AP, so technically I'm done :)   (To be clear, I'm not mad)
